Best way to build Cython packages with inter-dependancies?
Say for example i have 2 .pyx files
file1.pyx (filled with some functions)
file2.pyx
Inside file2 statements like import/cimport fx_from_file1 will be used. Now naturally i want to build file1 first so that i can test these imports anyway. But say i already know everything works. Is it reasonable to build both at the same time in the same build file? Or should i do it one at a time depending on my import statements?
What is the usual procedure in this case, because if i need to build a lot of these i cannot just to it one by one so i assume it i reasonable to do it all at the same time anyway

You are using cython, so you are going on compiler language world, so you should uses compilers tools to organize your building process, e.g. make and other tools.

Yes. You can build them in the same build file. There's no need to worry about building one first (usually... I'm sure there's edge cases I'm missing)
